# layout and outer margins

Tags: r, plot, graphics

Is it true that `layout` function ignores the outer margin parameters set with `par`? I read so in a lecture note. But I don't think it is right.

Below is my explanation:

```
par(oma = rep(4, 4))
layout(matrix(1:4, 2, 2))
layout.show(4)
```

Does anyone have further insights to this?

Comment: How is it supposed to look like in your example?

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation of `?layout` the following warning is given:

These functions are totally incompatible with the other mechanisms for arranging plots on a device: `par(mfrow)`, `par(mfcol)` and `split.screen`.

That does not mean you cannot set outer margins using `oma` in `par` in combination with `layout`. It only means that you can use only one of either (1) `mfrow`/`mfcol`, (2) `layout` or (3) `splitscreen`.

Also, you could look up the documentation for `mfrow`, `mfcol` and `splitscreen` for further insights.

Is this of any help?